# Matlab Optimisation - Minimise objective function using genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I want to set up the generic algorithm for a function that includes roughly 400 lines of script. The script itself is an optimisation process and I want to use the genetic algorithm to find the best input parameters into the optimisation process (`M` and `OPratio`). `M` lies between `0 and 10^7` and `OPratio` between `0 and 1`.
The function of the script is:

```
 NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)
```

set up for the genetic algorithm:

```
nvars = 2;    % Number of variables
LB = [0 0];   % Lower bound
UB = [10000000 1];  % Upper bound
X0 = [6670000 0.45]; % Start point 
options.InitialPopulationMatrix = X0;
[M,OPratio,fval] = ga(cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio),nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB)
```

I get following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'M'.
```

I am new to optimisation and the genetic algorithm so would appreciate any help, please let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I am assuming that the objective is to minimize the Objective function `cut_off_optimisation`.

Now first update your function to look like this

```
function y = cut_off_optimisation(x)    
M=x(1);
OPratio=x(2);

%
% paste body of your currently used function here
%

y=NPVtotal ;
```

Now use this code to minimize your objective function.

```
nvars = 2;    % Number of variables
LB = [0 0];   % Lower bound
UB = [10000000 1];  % Upper bound
X0 = [6670000 0.45]; % Start point 
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf},'Display','iter','InitialPopulation',X0);
[x,fval] = ga(@cut_off_optimisation,nvars,[],[],[],[],...
              LB,UB,[],options);
M=x(1);
OPratio=x(2);
```

**Update:** If you don't want to update your function. Just run this main code. Keep the function `NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)` in the same folder as that of the main code.

```
objectiveFunction=@(x)cut_off_optimisation(x(1),x(2));
nvars = 2;    % Number of variables
LB = [0 0];   % Lower bound
UB = [10000000 1];  % Upper bound
X0 = [6670000 0.45]; % Start point 
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf},'Display','iter','InitialPopulation',X0);
[x,fval] = ga(objectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],...
              LB,UB,[],options);
M=x(1);
OPratio=x(2);
fval
M
OPratio
```

**Update:** For getting final population members and fitness values. Replace the above ga function call statement to below statement.

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = ga(objectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);
M=x(1);
OPratio=x(2);
```

In here `population` will have the members of the final population and `score` will have fitness values for the final population. Default population size is `20`. So you will have `20 rows` in both the matrix. Number of columns in `population` will be equivalent to `number of variables` in the problem and `score` will be a column matrix. You can change the population size by adding option `PopulationSize` to `gaoptimset`.

```
options = gaoptimset('PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf},'Display','iter','InitialPopulation',X0,'PopulationSize',30);
```

To know more about the `options` available for `gaoptimset` and their expected `values` and their `{default values}`. Go to matlab help and search for `gaoptimset`. There you will find a table with all these details. Here is the link from matlab website http://in.mathworks.com/help/gads/gaoptimset.html .There may be changes according to your matlab version. So its better to use help in matlab.

Comment: Thanks for you answer: in the %past body of function here ... do you mean the complete script of the function or just the function ?

Comment: And another question - do I have to save the new function or can i just basically run your code in a script?

Comment: OK, I will update the post to make it a bit more easier to implement

Comment: Use the code in the update part of the answer. No need to update anything else. Just run this code. Make sure the function `NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)` is in the same folder from which the this code is executed.

Comment: no need now to define x1 and x2 ? ... i will try the updated code in a second but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Nothing else is needed. Just copy it to a new file,Save it. Copy, function `NPVtotal = cut_off_optimisation(M,OPratio)` to the same folder in which the new code is saved. Now run the new code.

Comment: is it possible to write the code in a way that for OPratio it only searches for the third decimal place and not further ? and for M in steps of 10000 ? as this is the highest accuracy possible for my process - so i dont need it computed more accurately.

Comment: is it possible to dertermine how close the ga comes to the optimum result ? and further is it possible to display the mutations or what the algorithm is doing ? thanks

Comment: For the first question. I don't think there is a straight forward way for doing that. For three decimal places, you can `multiply upper bound and lower bound by 1000` and for M, `divide upper and lower bounds by 10000` and use `Integer ga Algorithm`. For integer ga algorithm check this link http://in.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html

Comment: For the second question. In the matlab help search for `gaoptimset` and you can see all the options and their possible values in there.

Comment: For plot there are various options @gaplotbestf | @gaplotbestindiv | @gaplotdistance | @gaplotexpectation | @gaplotgeneology | @gaplotmaxconstr | @gaplotrange | @gaplotselection | @gaplotscorediversity | @gaplotscores | @gaplotstopping you can do multiple plots like this `'PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf,@gaplotdistance}`.

Comment: For easy usage you can also use the GUI. Type `optimtool` in command window and in the place of `Solver` choose `ga - Genetic Algorithm` and fill all the required parameters in there and click `Start`

Comment: awesome thanks for your help. last simple questions for today - when does the algorithm stop ? and how do i know its finished ? and how can I display the values for M and OPratio then ?

Comment: For that go to matlab help search for gaoptimset. In there there is a list of options,Description,Values and their {default values}. In there there are various halt parametes like `Generations - maximum number of iterations before the algorithm halts` Default values `100`. This is just one parameter. So read it. You can change these values by adding to `gaoptimset` in the above code.

Comment: After optimization, the minimized value will be there in the variable `M` and `OPratio` and `fval` will have the best fitness value of that function. Also best fitness value and mean will be there in the top of the plot generated by `@gaplotbestf`.

Comment: You can just display the values M and OPratio and fval by typing it without semicolon at the end of the code. You can check in above code.

Comment: perfect 100 thanks. Last, last question for today - is it also possible to somehow see the best 5 or 10 values ? or do i have to store the data for that ?

Comment: `[M,OPratio,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = ga(objectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);` Collect the required values from those variables. If that is not enough, read the option `OutputFcns` in `gaoptimset` matlab help.

Comment: Good morning, I tried storing the data from the genetic algorithm but creating zero arrays and writing in them. But as there is no iteration variable it only overrides the first value. Any solution on how to store the data ?

Comment: [M,OPratio,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = ga(objectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options); using this what you described 2 comments earlier comes out with " using too many output argument" ... do i somehow need to define the variables in "options" ?

Comment: You don't have to do any iteration. After running ga with `[M,OPratio,fval,exitflag,output,population,score] = ga(objectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],options);`. `population` Matrix ( Matrix whose rows contain the members of the final population) will have multiple rows and two columns (since number of variables is 2). First column contains values used for `M` during final population and Second column contains values used for `OPratio` and `score`(Column vector of the fitness values of the final population.) contains the corresponding function values.

Comment: Number of rows in `population` matrix  and `score` will be 20 by default. Because size of the population is by `default 20` and the matrix contains the members of the final population. You can change the size of the population by adding option `'PopulationSize'` in `gaoptimset`.

Comment: Your next questions answer. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry,my mistake. Instead of `M,OPratio` use `x`. Then do `M=x(1);
    OPratio=x(2);`.

Comment: I have updated the answer above. That will solve your second question.